How do I place a custom link in the Laravel Voyager administrator?
I want to place in the Laravel Voyager administrator menu a link for a custom view that I have, not for a CRUD. But, I want to do it directly from a Seeder, so that it is not deleted in case I freshen the database.
I am doing the seeder to the menu_items table. And I was entering this data, but it doesn't appear in the menu:
array(
            'id' => 42,
            'menu_id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Importar Datos',
            'url' => '/import',
            'target' => '_self',
            'icon_class' => 'voyager-settings',
            'color' => '#000000',
            'parent_id' => NULL,
            'order' => 11,
            'created_at' => '2021-08-07 18:52:09',
            'updated_at' => '2021-11-19 18:12:03',
            'route' => 'import.get',
            'parameters' => NULL,
        ),

Say that the url you have to redirect to is /import and the route is import.get
Could you help me know how the data has to be for it to appear, please?

According to the fact that you have already define a routeName in your seeder. Why not directly return the full link with route($routeName).
Your new code should look like
array(
            'id' => 42,
            'menu_id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Importar Datos',
            'url' => route('import.get', [ /*put params here if you have*/ ]),
            'target' => '_self',
            'icon_class' => 'voyager-settings',
            'color' => '#000000',
            'parent_id' => NULL,
            'order' => 11,
            'created_at' => '2021-08-07 18:52:09',
            'updated_at' => '2021-11-19 18:12:03',
            'route' => 'import.get',
            'parameters' => NULL,
        ),

Or you can create a link anywhere using route() too
$customlink = route($voyager->route, [ /*put params here if you have*/ ]);

